# Is it good to call `new` twice for each object in an array, when create an array of objects and initialize them differently?

Tags: c#, arrays

When creating a array of objects of a class and the number of objects in the array is only determined at runtime, how can I initialize each object in the array differently?

For example, `SimpleJob` is a class. I want to create an array of objects of `SimpleJob`, and initialize them differently

```
SimpleJob[] jobs = new SimpleJob[nbJobs]; 
for (int i = 1; i <= nbJobs; ++i)
{
    jobs[i-1] = new SimpleJob(i, false);
}
```

I call `new` twice for each object in the array.
Is it a good way, or just wasting the allocated memory? I am relating to my knowledge about `new` in C++.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < nbJobs; ++i)` perhaps?

Comment: Your method is perfectly fine other than the indexer that @alexD pointed out.  What else do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: What does **differently** mean to you in "how can I initialize each object in the array differently"?

Comment: You're getting down- and close-votes. You need to fix question quickly to avoid it being closed.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated. I feel that calling `new` twice for each object in the array might be wasting. Is it correct?

Comment: You are NOT calling new twice. How do you get the idea that you call new twice?

Comment: @NineBerry one `new` when creating the array outside the loop, and a `new` for each object in the array in the loop. Am I right?

Comment: @Tim - You're calling `new` on the array and `new` on each instance - there's no redundancy here at all.

Comment: @Enigmativity  If some code in C++ is similar, will there be redundeancy and some bad consequence?

Comment: @Tim - What does it matter is there is similar C++ code?

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling `new` twice.

```
SimpleJob[] jobs = new SimpleJob[nbJobs];
```

This creates an array of *potential* references to `SimpleJob` objects. The array doesn't actually contain any `SimpleJob` objects yet. And no `SimpleJob` objects are created anywhere. Each element of the array is a `null` reference.

Note that in C#, variables of a class type are always references to objects.

---

Tip: Instead of using arrays, use `List<>` objects.

```
List<SimpleJob> jobs = new List<SimpleJob>(); 

for (int i = 1; i <= nbJobs; ++i)
{
   jobs.Add(new SimpleJob(i, false));
}
```

Then you don't need to know how many entries you are going to have.

Comment: It is not correct if `SimpleJob` is a `struct` though.

Comment: @AlexD True, that's why I wrote "class type" :)

Comment: Then the answer should start with something like "Assuming SimpleJob is a class" :). Otherwise the statement "_Each element of the array is a null reference._" is technically incorrect.